# Converting ISO::DateTime to number format

Tags: qt, c++11, datetime-format

I want to change the date time format to numbers only so that it can be incremented.

Current Implementation is saved as `QString 2019-03-13T09:01:22+01:0`

Expected result: ***201903120858031***

Answer (score 1):

qt is a really powerful framework, you are just coding a solution in a wrong way.

Imagine the pain in the back just validating dates, leap years etc etc

every date and dateTime has the methods to do calendar math operations.

see this example as ref:

```
//
QDateTime dateOrigin = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QDateTime ReturnDate = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QString isoDate{dateOrigin.toString(Qt::ISODate)};
qDebug() << "before: " << isoDate;
ReturnDate = dateOrigin.addDays(1);
ReturnDate = dateOrigin.addMonths(1);
ReturnDate = dateOrigin.addYears(1);
qDebug() << "after: " << ReturnDate.toString(Qt::ISODate);
//
```

update:
lets suppose that **201903120858031** is a date time formated as **yyyyMMddHHmmss**, then you can convert that to a long

```
//201903120858031
//yyyyMMddHHmmss
qDebug() << "after: " << ReturnDate.toString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
qDebug() << "after as long number: " << ReturnDate.toString("yyyyMMddHHmmss").toLong();
```

producing the output:

> before:  "2019-02-28T12:43:33"
>
> after:  "20200228124333"
>
> after as number:  20200228124333

Comment: Actually, the requirement is to show the time in the number format as I have written in the question.

Comment: perfect, tnxs for the clarification, see please my update